# How to print the location of Maven dependency generated in Gradle?

Tags: java, maven, plugins, gradle

I'm using the Gradle Maven plugin and I'm used to see the location of the generated Jars when using Maven.

How to print the location of the Maven dependency after the build finishes... Something like this:

```
$ gradle clean install:clean
:compileJava
:processResources
:classes
:jar
:install
Installed at /home/mdesales/.m2/repository/com/x/platform/listeners/x-asynclistener/1.0.0/x-asynclistener-1.0.0.jar

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 4.181 secs
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "doLast" to capture the event after the installation is performed, as described at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/tutorial_using_tasks.html.

I'm not sure if there's a property with the location of the jar, but I built it with the following gradle properties:

```
apply plugin: 'maven'

install.doLast {
    def mavenRepoDir = System.getProperty("user.home") + "/.m2/repository/"
    def projectGroupDir = project.group.replace(".", "/") + "/"
    def jarName = project.name + "-" + project.version + ".jar"
    println ("Jar installed at " + mavenRepoDir + projectGroupDir + project.name + "/" + project.version + "/" + jarName)
}
```

Running gradle with the command described will print the appropriate value! Don't forget to include the maven plugin.

```
$ gradle clean install:clean
:compileJava
:processResources
:classes
:jar
:install
Installed at /home/mdesales/.m2/repository/com/x/platform/listeners/x-asynclistener/1.0.0/x-asynclistener-1.0.0.jar

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 4.181 secs
```